# jQuery: Pre-referencing element handles as variables for dynamically-added elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, element

I am trying make my code a bit neater by declaring all the elements I need to work with as varibles initally, like so:

```
var templateDiv = $(".enquiry-step");
var holder      = $("#template-holder");
```

However, some of these elements don't actually exist on the page yet. After I've added them (with ajax), when I try to do something like:

```
templateDiv.fadeIn(250);
```

It doesn't work, but this does:

```
$(".enquiry-step").fadeIn(250);
```

I assume this is because `var templateDiv = $(".enquiry-step");` is actually doing more than I assumed- ie. creating an object with various properties derived from the element... which it can't do if the element doesn't yet exist in the DOM? Am I right?

If so, then is there any other way of setting the handle as a variable, or will I just have to keep referencing these elements like `$(".enquiry-step")` throughout my code?

**EDIT** : Using console.log() after the element has been created dynamically gives the following:

**console.log(templateDiv):**

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → enquiries, selector: ".enquiry-step" }
```

**console.log($(".enquiry-step"));**

```
Object { 0: <div.uk-grid.enquiry-step>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → enquiries, selector: ".enquiry-step" }
```

Note the difference... I don't understand why?

Comment: is it possible to post fiddle?

Comment: Might take a while, hold on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".enquiry-step")
```

the call to $() invokes the creation of a jQuery object that is returned to you. Basically it is a wrapper to the dom element(s) mathced by the selector. If the elements are not present at the moment of object creation, the wrapper is there but it doesn't reference any DOM elements (see .length being 0), and it doesn't watch the DOM tree in order to update itself when these elements appear e.g. it's completely static. I would recommend for you to simply declare your variable

```
var holder;
```

and only assign a value to it at the moment where the elements are in DOM

```
holder= $(".enquiry-step");
```

Basically calling $() is like making a database query - it will only return results if they are already in the DB.